# jQuery won't find elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js code:

```
(function($, undefined) {
    $("a").click(function(event) { //or another elemtnt
        alert('Hello!');
    })
})(jQuery);
```

And of course link:

```
<a href="http://google.ru/" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

the JS code doesn't work, but if I change it to:

```
(function($, undefined) {
    $("*").click(function(event) {
        alert('Hello!');
    })
})(jQuery);
```

all works!

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: If add this code in console (chrome) - all perfect http://jsfiddle.net/A2WhV/

Comment: it also works in the former case : http://jsfiddle.net/KsFWZ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've put your JavaScript before the `a` node is loaded the effect will be something like you described. Try this instead:

```
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function(event) { //or another elemtnt
        alert('Hello!');
    })
});
```

This will invoke the anonymous function when the DOM tree is ready. Here is an example in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttMHC/3/).

When you use `*` as selector jQuery adds click handler to the `html` element, that's why you get the alert.

Answer (score 0):

why don´t you try with document.ready?

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $('a').click(function (){
        alert("a");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

why don't you give an ID to it and select for `$('#my-id')` for setting the event?